# C language: Difference between float and void in functions

Tags: java, c, void

I'm learning how to use the functions in C but I can't understand why while this:

```
    float TableauDebut(float size[], float poi[], char sex[], int nbElem)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < nbElem; i++){
    printf("  %d)%.2f  %.2f  ", i, size[i], poi[i]);
    switch(sex[i]){
        case 'F': printf("Woman\n"); break;
        case 'M': printf("Man\n"); break;
    }
}
```

displays my table as well as using **void**

But when I try to do the same in Java:

```
static void TableauDebut(double [] size, double [] poi, char [] sex, int nbElem)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0; i < nbElem; i++){
    System.out.printf("  %d)%.2f  %.2f  ", i, size[i], poi[i]);
    switch(sex[i]){
        case 'F': System.out.printf("Femme\n"); break;
        case 'M': System.out.printf("Homme\n"); break;
    }
}
```

I can just use **void** and not **double**

What's the difference between using float and void in C language and why I cannot do the same in Java?

Comment: Really, you should fix the C function so that it also return void, or to actually return something, e.g. error code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `void` return type means your function doesn't return a value. Anything else means your function must return an object of that type (or, where applicable, something that is *convertible* to that type.)

Your first example promises to return a `float` but fails to do so. This is an error, but a C compiler need not tell you about this. With suitable compiler settings you should get a warning, but the bottom line is that it is possible to compile such an erroneous piece of code in C, run it, and get *undefined behaviour* at runtime.

Java protects you against this and fails to compile the code.

Comment: So, it's a problem due to a bad setting in my compiler in C? In other words, Java is more exact in regards to code-writing?

Comment: @Sandra It really depends on the age and quality of the compiler. With a recent clang and the `-Wall` option, I get `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`. There are also settings to make warnings into errors. In general Java is less tolerant of this kind of thing.